# How can I get disabled inputs in Post

Tags: html, post, disabled-input

I am using the Google Address Autofill to populate some disabled inputs on the form.  The idea is that

- The user can see the data I am going to save (because not every field returned by Google is saved).
- And they can not interfere with it and give an invalid mismatched set of fields.

Because the inputs are **disabled**, I cant see them in $POST when the form is submitted.  I could mirror each field onto a hidden but enabled input.  Is there a cleaner way to do this ?

Comment: The elements must first be 1) enabled or; 2) JavaScript must be used to provide the data via another means (shadow elements, custom submission). And that's pretty much it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect them using javascript and add them to the url of the next form and attach it to the button.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable them via javascript when the form is submitted. Give your form an ID, I've called it formId below, and then add the following right before your closing `</body>` tag

```
<script>
var form = document.getElementById('formId').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
        inputs[i].setAttribute('disabled',false);
    }
    this.submit();
    for (var i = 0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
        inputs[i].setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I thought about this.  I am concerned that if there is an error (such as temporary loss of internet connection) then the fields remain enabled and a second post could then send invalid user modified data.

Comment: Might happen when things go really really wrong. I've edited the opposite in after form submission. But keep in mind that changing the input field from disabled to enabled doesn't require more than open the console and just edit the html. So you can't be sure that nothing was changed that shouldn't be changed either way. @RohitGupta

Comment: What you could do is to collect googles autofill data server side and validate the input coming from your form submission with that data. And if that fails redirect back with an error saying that the form was manipulated. HTML and Javascript both are very easy to change by your users. @RohitGupta

Comment: True, but I if they are going to do that then I cant stop them doing other things. I can only guard against user activity on the client side.  The rest has to be on the server.  Unless I use ajax to submit the data direct from the json returned from google.

Comment: Yes, that's how it is. @RohitGupta